# VLC stream problem

Tags: video, 16.04, vlc

On Ubuntu 16.04, when I play video with VLC it looks like this:

[image]

I reinstalled it but no change.
Other players work fine.

What's wrong ?

Comment: What kind of video file are you trying to play? (My guess is this has to do with VLC's decoding of your video file.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to delete the vlc settings as described in http://sourcedigit.com/16683-how-to-solve-3-common-problems-with-vlc-in-ubuntu-15-0414-0414-10/

I found another hint wich solved the problem for me:
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=132705

*"...in Preferences => Input / Codecs => Hardware-accelerated decoding. Set to "Disable"..."*